# what is the difference between install an apk using adb and install it by downloading from host

Tags: android

what is the difference between install an apk using adb and install it by downloading from a host?

When I download my apk (self-signed, because I'm in develop stage. It is not in market, I download from my localhost) to the device, by its internet connection, and I install it, then my application reproduces some bugs, in general the application works fine but, some bugs appear.
Anyway, when I install the application by adb way, those bug disappear.

Note: to do this install I enable the option: settings->applications->"Unknown sources" in my device.
Note: All this in debug mode 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference, it sounds like you have two different versions of the apk....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference except that for a download you need the "Unknown Sources" checked.

A note though, all APK's are self signed, even ones in the market.